# Connecting ThinkPad T410 (Windows 7) to Macbook (OSX 10.6) through ethernet cable

Tags: windows-7, macos, macbook, ethernet, thinkpad

I have searched and read a few other forums for this solution but have yet to be able to accomplish this task. I want to connect my Windows 7 laptop to my Macbook to share large files (10GB or larger) via ethernet speeds using FTP (since Windows 7 now has a native ftp client). I know there are work-arounds such as firewire (although I haven't tried that yet) but I would like to know how to accomplish this for furture reference.

What I have done thus far:

-connected ThinkPad to Macbook via cross over cable

-created ad hoc network on Macbook

-clicked on "unidentified network" for Windows 7

That's where the problems begin. I get an IP on my Macbook and can see the ThinkPad in my finder but for whatever reason I cannot connect to the "device". Also I cannot see my Macbook from the Windows laptop. I've tried diagnosing the problem on Windows but all that really does is restart the LAN port and still no changes. Can anyone help me with step by step instructions? Oh, and just to point out; I can see both my Mac and Windows laptops from the other when I am on wireless. I don't want to transfer 10GB files via wireless.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're too cheap to just buy a router that supports gigabit ethernet, try to setup static IPs manually:

1. Connect the computers with a crossover cable.  Since most gigabit devices support auto-MDX a regular patch cable may work too.
2. Pick a IP subnet not likely to be in use by one of your other adaptors.  I'd suggest something like 192.168.100.x with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.
3. Stop using DHCP and set your IP and subnet mask manually.

   - Mac: System Preferences->Network->Ethernet (left side)->Configure IPv4->"Manually"
   - Win7: Control Panel->Network and Internet->Change Adaptor Settings->Right Click your device and select properties. Select 'Internet Protocol Version 4' and click properties.
4. Assign each machine it's own IP address in the network you chose above (192.168.100.x where x is between 2-254) for example:

   - Mac: 192.168.100.2, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, Default Router: 192.168.100.1 (or empty)
   - Win: 192.168.100.3, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, Default Router: 192.168.100.1 (or empty)
5. Launch terminal on the mac or a command prompt under Windows and ping the other machine by typing the following and pressing enter: `ping 192.168.100.2`

If it doesn't work, check/disable your firewalls on both ends.  Assuming you can ping, you've now got a working IP connection between the two machines and you can just connect to the IP of the other machine using FTP, SMB or whatever.  Don't try and browse in Finder/Explorer to the other networked device, just tell it where to go:

- Windows: Start->Run: `\\192.168.100.2` (for SMB) or  `ftp://192.168.100.2` (for FTP)
- Mac: Apple+K from Finder: `smb://192.168.100.3` (for SMB) or `ftp://192.168.100.3` (for FTP).

With Network Location Profiles (mac) and ThinkVantage Access Connections (win) you should be able to create profiles to switch from your normal dynamic IP configuration (DHCP) to your static one with a couple clicks if you have to do this more than once.  Or, you know...buy a router with a couple gigE ports.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably suggest running the internet connection sharing wizard on the windows box - having the windows box 'share' an internet connection and connecting the mac to the windows box - the windows box acts as the 'router' in this case, and should have an ip address of 192.168.0.1, and your mac acts as the client. You can then transfer files over whatever file transfer protocol you prefer. Considering how recent both boxes are, you should be expecting gig-e speeds.